# How to scroll through large database without huge load times and large ram usage

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I am making an application to display music in an iTunes like view. It is a tableLayout which is created from a SQLite database. I load the list of songs into the table using an asyncTask at startup. This works great for 0-100 ish songs, but too many more and the startup time is huge as is the ram usage. It feels very unnecessary to load the entire database into ram at one time even on a separate thread as only a few rows can be seen at one time. How can I dynamically load and unload the rows from this view as the user scrolls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [Cursors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) and [Cursor Adapters.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html) These mechanisms are provided to do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I am using a cursor at the moment -  Cursor c=myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName + " ORDER BY " + params[0], null);  How can I use a CursorAdapter or fix my cursor to do this?

Comment: @ghostbust555: What are you doing with the data from the `Cursor` after you make that DB query?

Comment: if (c != null){ do{ add c's info to a table row and add the table row to the tableLayout} while(c.moveToNext())}

Comment: @ghostbust555: Any reason you're using a table layout instead of a `ListView`? With the latter you'd just use a `CursorAdapter` and override the adaper's `getViewValue`method. There are only a finite number of `ListView` items generated at any one time making it very fast even with a `Cursor` handling a large number of items.

Comment: I tried to make it in a ListView but I could not get it to work :( I guess I will try again, thanks for the help. Is there any way I could achieve the same thing with a tableLayout in a scroll view though?

Comment: A Cursor updates its internal query as you use the data. If you are filling out an entire TableLayout you are going to iterate over every item in the Cursor, completely ruining its purpose. When you use a cursor adapter with a list view, the query is limited and only the items that are visible will be queried from the database and built into items. The solution you are looking for is to move away from a table layout, which won't meet your needs except on trivially small data sets.